# Is lsblk not available for Ubuntu10.04?

Tags: software-installation

I tried to install `lsblk`, but I got this error message:

```
# apt-get install lsblk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package lsblk
```

I am using Ubuntu Server 10.04 64-bit.

If lsblk is not available then what is the best substitution for it?

Comment: `lsblk` is a default command.Why did you try to install it.

Comment: # lsblk
No command 'lsblk' found, did you mean:
Command 'lslk' from package 'lslk' (universe)
lsblk: command not found

Comment: exactly how you call `lsblk`? What's the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: just `lsblk` the output of echo $PATH is `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the @Oli's [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434150/is-lsblk-not-available-for-ubuntu10-04#comment564685_434152) , `lsblk` was not included in the util-linux package for  Ubuntu 10.04 LTS versions.

See [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/amd64/util-linux/filelist) Ubuntu 10.04's `util-linux` package file list.So you can't able to run `lsblk` command on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Comment: it said "util-linux is already the newest version."

Comment: try to reinstall it by running `sudo apt-get install --reinstall util-linux`

Comment: still not working.

Comment: did you have coreutils package `sudo apt-get install coreutils`.

Comment: i tried but still not working.

Comment: @AvinashRaj [`lsblk` isn't in Lucid's version of `util-linux`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/amd64/util-linux/filelist)

Comment: can i install util-linux for precise version on lucid?

Comment: no, i think it's not safe.

Answer (score 6):

Use blkid from the util-linux package instead:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install util-linux

blkid
```

Comment: This command worked for me; I didn't even have to install anything.  I did have to have root permissions to see anything.

Comment: `sudo blkid` will list all your partitions.

Answer (score 0):

(about ten years later) meet same situation on an old pc.

yes, ubuntu10 util-linux no lsblk command.

### one workaround: get binary from other version .deb

I steal a binary from other release version (maybe ubuntu14) util-linux deb,
and it just work.

```bash
# I use x86 system, you can find other arch in same directory of this link
$ wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/util-linux/util-linux_2.20.1-1ubuntu3.1_i386.deb

$ mkdir OUT

$ dpkg -x util-linux_2.20.1-1ubuntu3.1_i386.deb OUT

$ ls -lh OUT/bin/lsblk
-rwxr-xr-x 1 chen chen 43K 2014-06-18 09:21 OUT/bin/lsblk
```

### other workaround: compile from source

I tried  util-linux v2.38.1.tar.gz.
not success, maybe system to old for the last version of util-linux.
I didn't try other version.